# Customize Amazon SES address verification request email

Tags: php, amazon-ses, bulk-email

To send emails through Amazon SES, a user is required to verify the:

1. Sender email address/domain, and
2. Recipient email addresses

Since, I have production access, issue 2 is taken care of, but to verify sender email address/domain, I need to send a request through the SES console or the api. Amazon in turn sends a verification email to the sender email address.

**Question:** Is it possible to customize the address verification request email sent by Amazon SES? I searched and haven't been able to find any documentation to this effect. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks!

P.S. - I use PHP to interface with Amazon SES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you verify your domain with a DKIM all the emails sent by you (by hand or not) will result under you domain

[ses docs - easy dkim](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim.html)